# How to simulate sequential registers from causal ones?

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, dc.distributed-comp, concurrency

**Background:** In distributed shared memory (DSM) model, the problem of *register simulations/constructions* is to simulate registers with certain characteristic out of registers with weaker features. For example, we can construct the strongest multi-writer multi-reader atomic $\texttt{read/write}$ registers from the weakest single-writer multi-reader safe ones [1].

**Question:**

> Is it possible to simulate sequential registers from causal ones in DSM model? And how to, if possible?

I guess the answer is negative. However, I have no idea how to prove/disprove it (Googling does not help on this).

---

[1] The Art of Multiprocessor Programming. By Maurice Herlihy and Nir Shavit (Chapter 4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer my own question:** The answer is (*probably*; please let me know if I am wrong) negative: it is impossible to simulate sequential registers from causal registers.

**Note:** the following proof is indirect. And I am still interested in a direct proof.

> Theorem: It is impossible to simulate sequential registers from causal registers.

Proof: In the thesis [1], Kawash shows that causal consistency memory (with only $\texttt{read/write}$ operations) cannot solve mutual exclusion. However, [Lamport's bakery algorithm (wiki)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport's_bakery_algorithm), when run on sequential consistency memories, solves mutual exclusion.

---

[1] [Limitations and Capabilities of Weak Memory Consistency Systems](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.136.7383&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Jalal Y. Kawash, PhD Thesis, 2000.